# Adjective plus noun in a sentence

Tags: grammar, writing

When describing a charts, Is there a way to use adjective plus noun other than using there is or there was.

Can I say, the consumption of fast food had a gradual increase over the years.

The mobile phone services had a moderated growth.

Comment: Yes, and you can use 'experienced' instead of 'had' in such sentences.

Comment: Yes, but more natural would be: "The consumption of fast food has/had gradually increased over the years", and "The mobile phone services had seen a moderated growth".

Comment: @BillJ: Don't feed the bears! Just because OP's original includes ***had = experienced / underwent*** is no reason to use a Perfect form when recasting. Simple Past *The consumption of fast food gradually increased over the years* accurately and more simply reflects the temporal aspect of the original,

Comment: Thank you all. Thank you @BillJ for your contribution. Your sentence (The consumption of fast food had gradually increased over the years)  if I omit the word (had) does the meaning change?

Comment: The past perfect places the action before some other event or situation. But if you intend to simply refer to past time, then your suggested alternant is fine

Comment: But there is no need for either of the nouns *increase* and *growth*. Better would be to use the verbs from which they derive: *The consumption of fast food **increased gradually** over the years* and *The mobile phone services **grew moderately***.